# Изменить координаты SVG для тега <g/> при наведении

Tags: javascript, html5, svg

У меня есть массив координат `х` и `у`:

```
var coordinateX = [10,20,30,40,50,....];
var coordinateY = [10,20,30,40,50,....]:
```

Эти координаты являются центрами окружностей, в которых я хочу показать всплывающую подсказку при наведении курсора на окружность.

```
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].addEventListener('mousemove', show);
    circles[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}
```

Tooltip`представлен в виде элемента`g` с прямоугольником и текстом внутри.

```
<g id="poligon" visibility="hidden" class="element">
  <rect width="80" height="20" fill="white"/>
  <text class="tooltip" x="4" y="15" dominant-baseline="centered">Tooltip</text>
</g>

var poligon = svgDoc.getElementById("poligon")

function show(evt) {
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate(" + coordinateX[i] + ", " + coordinatey[i] + ")");
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
  textTooltipVrijednost.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "class");    
}

function hide(){
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
}
```

Я попытался применить `translate` для g-элемента, используя `setAttribute` и изменив значения `x`, `y` атрибута `translate`, но я получил только последнее значение позиции.

Как сделать это динамически для каждой позиции?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/a/56428697/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Лучшей идеей было бы использовать элемент HTML в качестве всплывающей подсказки.
Таким образом, у вас не возникнет проблем при небольших размерах элемента SVG, когда текст может стать настолько маленьким, что вы не сможете его прочитать.

Основная идея - определить положение мыши над элементом SVG. Если мышь входит в круг, всплывающая подсказка становится видимой и занимает положение мыши. Также в этом случае отображаются координаты круга. Когда мышь покидает круг, отображение всплывающей подсказки возвращается к нулю.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let coordinates = [{
  cx: 10,
  cy: 7,
  r: 5
}, {
  cx: 10,
  cy: 30,
  r: 5
}, {
  cx: 50,
  cy: 10,
  r: 5
}, {
  cx: 33,
  cy: 25,
  r: 5
}];

let circles = [];

coordinates.forEach(c => {
  circles.push(drawCircle(c, svg));
})

circles.forEach((c, i) => {
  c.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    let m = oMousePos(svg, e);
    let cx = coordinates[i].cx;
    let cy = coordinates[i].cy;
    tooltip.style.display = "block";
    tooltip.style.left = m.x + "px";
    tooltip.style.top = m.y + "px";
    tooltip.innerHTML = `${cx}, ${cy}`;
  })
  c.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    tooltip.style.display = "none";
  })
})




function drawCircle(o, parent) {

  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}



function oMousePos(svg, evt) {
  var ClientRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100vh;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 60 40"></svg>

  <div id="tooltip">0,0</div>

</div>
```